# Why can't my user account remove an AD Computer in Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have created a `Computer` account in `OU=AutoCreatedVMs,OU=Computer`. I have allowed the AD Group `Join-Move-Delete VMs` to Create/delete Computer objects in OU AutoCreatedVMs:

[image: Screenshot of AutoCreatedVMs OU Permissions]

I have an account called `svc_jenkins` and made it a member of AD Group `Join-Move-Delete VMs`.

I can't delete VMs from that OU when logged on as `svc_jenkins`:

```
PS C:\> gci env:username

Name                           Value
----                           -----
USERNAME                       svc_jenkins


PS C:\> Get-ADComputer test


DistinguishedName : CN=test,OU=AutoCreatedVMs,OU=Computer,DC=duck,DC=loc
DNSHostName       :
Enabled           : True
Name              : test
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : 7dd3b09a-d079-467a-b69f-90a2e30c363d
SamAccountName    : TEST$
SID               : S-1-5-21-1075642099-280362434-2919291742-3630
UserPrincipalName :



PS C:\> Get-ADComputer test|Remove-ADComputer -Confirm:$False
Remove-ADComputer : Access is denied
At line:1 char:21
+ Get-ADComputer test|Remove-ADComputer -Confirm:$False
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (CN=test,OU=Auto...,DC=duck,DC=loc:ADComputer) [Remove-ADComputer], Un
   authorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manag
   ement.Commands.RemoveADComputer
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong? Domain controller is Windows Server 2012 R2.

**UPDATE** I tried it again 20 minutes later and it worked. Nothing else changed.

Comment: I'm betting the first time you forgot to open powershell as an administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Powershell was already running as the service account when you added it to the group, that group membership wouldn't have applied to that session.  Did you perhaps open a new Powershell session later when it worked?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this might be it!

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one domain controller?

My guess is that the MMC was connected to one DC and you (or the powershell) tried to remove the computer object on the other, just before the security setting was replicated.

When you tried 20 minutes later, it was replicated granting you the permission.

Comment: No I have only one domain controller.